# What is the size of the stack in a C function?

Tags: c, function, stack

More precisely, given the following code

```
int funct(int n){
    int arr[n]; //suppose no optimization takes place
    return;
}
```

Is there a max n, such that a greather n will go on a space of another process ?

Is there a way to know and modify the size of the stack dedicated the current process (at runtime and/or at compile time) ?

Comment: The stack is determined by the implementation. The standard does not even required local variables to go onto a stack. You need to specify what implementation you are using (operating system, etc.) for this question to be answerable.

Comment: I dont think arr[n] is possible in C.

Comment: @bUff23: It has been for 20 years.

Comment: my bad I got confused with runtime allocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a max n, such that a greather n will go on a space of another process ?

Except on implementations in tiny microcontrollers without an MMU (where you likely don't have an OS with the notion of processes anyway), there exists no such n because processes live in completely different address spaces.

There are however values so large that the stack pointer will be adjusted to coincide with unrelated memory *in the same process*. This was repopularized under the name "stack clash" in 2017 after it was found that a lot of software was vulnerable to it. It's not that there's a certain limit on n, below which it's safe and above which you clobber unrelated memory. Almost surely there are one or more *guard pages* which will fault in between, and clashing requires a much larger n, crafted for the specific address you want to hit, that "jumps over" them all.

> Is there a way to know and modify the size of the stack dedicated the current process (at runtime and/or at compile time) ?

You absolutely can't change it at runtime because the stack is contiguous (assuming you'e not using an implementation with "split stack", which has its own huge set of problems and the address space you want to expand it into may already be assigned to something in your process. You may be able to change it at link time, e.g. `-Wl,-z,stack-size=nnnnnnn` on GCC/binutils with ELF targets, but operating systems may not actually honor it. I believe Windows tooling *does* have a way to set it that's honored though.

The right answer however is **DON'T DO THIS!** Do not make large or unbounded variable-length arrays. If you need that much storage, the cost of calling `malloc` is miniscule compared to whatever you're doing, and then you actually get to know whether it succeeded without crashing your program or introducing a gaping vulnerability.